# Couldn't able to send email using SendEmailAsync

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendmail

Good day,

I'm getting below exception, while sending email using SendGrid.

What would be the reason of causing this?

Below is my code.

```
    var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridApiKey"];
    var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
    var task = client.SendEmailAsync(sendGridMessage);
    task.Wait();
    var response = task.Result;
    return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, please don't post images of exceptions, instead paste the exception into your post. It makes things much easier for people to search on. Secondly, you should never be using `task.Wait()`, instead you should always be `await`ing.

Answer (score 0):

Verify SSL/TLS configuration: If you're using SSL/TLS for the connection, double-check that the SSL/TLS configuration is correct and up to date. Ensure that the certificate used by SendGrid is valid and trusted. If necessary, update the SSL/TLS settings or try using a different version of SSL/TLS.

Comment: Please share supporting link

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found a solution; after a lot of search, I found that I had to add this line of code in the Application_Start() function in global.asax.cs file.

System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)3072;